# Grails: enterprise level Grails

Tags: grails, enterprise

I am trying to persuade my boss about using Grails.
I tell him it is the most productive way to implement our shopping web site.

But he has doubts about its scalability when traffic gets higher and higher.

So can you give examples of enterprise level web sites with
notable traffic implemented in grails.

Also is there anything that I have to take into account when building
such an enterprise level web site that will probably have high
traffic.

Note: We may expect 10K daily hit.

Comment: What are the other technologies that you are considering for your shopping web site?

Comment: Tapestry, Spring, Hibernate is suggested also.

Comment: just say him `grails create-app AngryBoss` will create a project for you :D

Comment: 10k daily hit is nothing. Tell him you  can start worrying with a million daily hits.

Comment: We did a small grails app a year ago. We used jMeter and without major engineering saw that it could handle 100 simultaneous users running on a VM. With an average page rendering of 1 sec (say), this is > 8.6 million hits per day. I believe your question is not properly worded.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at the [Grails Success Stories](http://www.grails.org/Success+Stories). The most popular sites may be: Sky.com and mp3.walmart.com

Answer (score 6):

Groovymag has some good information on this but costs $5 per issue. [This issue](http://www.groovymag.com/main.issues.description/id=18/) has both an interview with a guy from Sky which is a very large site that uses grails as well as information in implementing an e-commerce site using Grails. The main point I got from reading the interview from one of the sky.com developers is that they have no problem scaling to millions of page views by smart use of caching. Although your site may have 10000 views a day most of those views should not need to access the database. You can cache information on each product available in order to limit the number of queries necessary when viewing the site. This should reduce the traffic on your database and make GORM less of a possible bottleneck. I have not been able to find out how GORM performs under heavy load, but if worse comes to worse you could write your performance critical database code using pure JDBC calls and put it in a service.

Comment: cache is the spelling you want :P

Answer (score 5):

If you do the math, 10K daily hits is less than one hit per second- even if all 10K hits happened during a 3 hour "peak traffic" window. Even assuming you meant "page renders" and not hits, you are talking about a really miniscule amount of traffic.